# How to change the way username validates in Django admin interface change form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-authentication, django-allauth

I can't override or edit the way the username is validated in the admin interface change form. I need my users to be able to have usernames with spaces and special characters.

I managed to edit the way the sign up form validates the username so on the client side the problem is solved. The thing is that when I try to edit a user in the admin interface, I get de following error:

> Enter a valid username. This value may contain only letters, numbers,
>   and @/./+/-/_ characters.

I can't find a way around this!

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override default django username validators for AbstractUser model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921900/override-default-django-username-validators-for-abstractuser-model)

Comment: Can answer it after looking at your form and views. You can add special characters, but I don't think you can add space in between username as you have mentioned `users to be able to have usernames with spaces and special characters.`.